# 10 things to do after installing 10.10

Tags: 10.10, installation

Just as the title says in your own opinion list the top 10 apps i should  install after a fresh ubuntu install. Please i need as many responses as possible(apps, tweaks,  update etc)

Comment: Be more specific, after the installation of Ubuntu, you can yawn, drink something, smash your machine, buy a new mouse, laugh, cry, ...

Comment: @Lekensteyn :)) Good one. @bernard I think the question will be closed in this way.Be more specific.

Comment: Please take it easy on i'm new to this site and ubuntu. I have edited my question, i hope it is more specific this time

Comment: should be community wiki.

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu and this site - as this question is highly subjective (IE: No one answer could ever be correct) it isn't suited for [this site](http://askubuntu.com/faq). For discussions like these they're best played out on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org) or [IRC](http://www.ubuntu.com/support/community/chat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Fix the buttons (move them to the right or reverse them)
2. Install Gnome-do
3. Install Docky
4. Re-theme
5. Activate ufw firewall
6. Install Kubuntu desktop (nice to have both options)

...

1. Make a backup copy of all your installed applications using Synaptic and store it offline. It makes rebuilding a machine much easier next time (you end up having 3 steps instead of 10+)

Comment: how do you make a back copy using synaptic

Comment: Start Synaptic, and select 'File/Save Markings As', enter the filename you wish to save as, and select the 'Save Full State, not only changes' option.

Answer (score 1):

[OMG!Ubuntu's Guide](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/10/10-things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-meerkat/)

> So you’ve downloaded Ubuntu 10.10, made yourself a freshly minted copy and installed it with haste. Now what?
>
> Here is our guide to the top 10 post-install must-do’s that will help ensure you get off to a marvellous start with the Maverick Meerkat.